# Event fired two times when clicked to button in my iOS. app

Tags: ios, events

I made a simple IOS. application where the UI contains buttons. For example I have nine buttons each button represent a number same as numeric keyboard. I made this buttons the following way, put it to the storyboard and made the Touch Up Inside event with ctrl drag functions, after I copied the buttons eight times.

The problem is when I pressed a button the event comes sometimes twice. It happens randomly. I put a break point into line NSLog I did not see faulty thing at all.

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([lastPressed isEqualToString:[sender currentTitle]]) {
        NSLog(@"Douple pressed digit"); // break it here
    }

    // store to lastPressed
    lastPressed = [sender currentTitle];
}
```

Comment: this code will print out to the log if the button is pressed two times too.. try to implement this method with only a single `NSLog` without condition. Also make `sender` being `id` typed in the signature. If you still see to lines, double check the connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you get multiple times in digitPressed when clicking once I would guess something went wrong when you copied the buttons so check the wiring in your storyboard.

And as Vince said it's a good practice to use id, it's not because this method gets triggered by buttons now that they should always be triggered by a button.

It's easier to debug when you log every time instead of only doubles.

```
NSLog(@"Button pressed: %@", [sender currentTitle]);
```

Comment: I don't know why, sometimes I got double events with a little delay

2012-02-17 18:22:58.190 Calc[318:fe03] Button pressed: 9
2012-02-17 18:22:58.263 Calc[318:fe03] Button pressed: 9